# Partial Display of email id in JSP. (Password Reset)

Tags: java, string, jsp

**Present Scenario**

when a user tries to reset his password,

Enter account number and submit. (ex:123456789)

(account number contains email in DB).

then displays *"Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to the address on file for account number :123456789".*

**So am trying to Display a Partial emailID to user.**

like `"Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to "Jo******pa@gmail.com" for account number :123456789".`

At present what i done is.

```
In Action class: (ResetPasswordAction.java)
String email =**retriving email id**
at end 
request.setAttribute("email", email);
before forwarding.


In Jsp (Display after email sent)
<c:out value="${email}"/>
```

Worked fine.

Now my question:

1) Is this the correct approach.

2) * How to replace String (email) with stars ** like "Jo******pa@gmail.com" . am trying, but is there any simple way. *Java 1.4

**Added:**

```
  String Str = "John.smithpa@gmail.com";
  String S=Str.replaceFirst("@(.*)","" );
  String mail=Str.replaceFirst("(.*)@","" );
  String trim=S.substring(2, S.length()-2);
  String star = trim.replaceAll(".", "*");
  String name= S.replaceAll(trim,star);
  String Disp=name+"@"+mail;
  System.out.println(Disp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like this:

```
String email="abcdef@xyz.com";
String str=email.replaceAll("(?<=..).(?=...*@)", "*");
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output:**

```
ab**ef@xyz.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that. simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

for question 2:
  what i can think out is use Regex,like follow:

```
           Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w{2}(.*)\\w{2}@.*");
           Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
           if (m.find(0)) {
                String star = m.group(1).replaceAll(".", "*");
                email = email.replace(m.group(1), star);
           }
```

but you'd make sure the email is in correct format.